# Make a Nested Widgets Responsive in Flutter

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, overflow

For simplicity, I have a `Container` and its child is a `Column`. The `Column` widget has two more `Container`.
Now the root `Container` is responsive and it resizes according to the screen but its child which is two `Container` inside `Column` doesn't resize and thus giving me render overflow. Manually setting `MediaQuery.of(context).size` to all the children widgets doesn't seem optimal.

The code,

```
Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: size.height * 0.3, //size = MediaQuery.of(context).size
        width: size.width * 0.3,
        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

I am wanting to resize the child `Container`s along with the parent `Container`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue correctly, you can achieve your objective using the `Flexible` `Widget` around your `Container`s:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: size.height * 0.3, //size = MediaQuery.of(context).size
        width: size.width * 0.3,
        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                width: 100,
                child: Text('This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. '),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                child: Text('This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. '),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can adjust how much space each `Container` inside the `Flexible` `Widget` takes by adjusting the `flex` property in each one.